# Google App engine Deoployment receives ERROR Only when specifiying CPUs above 1 in app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, gunicorn

I have a `Flask` app that deploys fine in the Google App Engine Flexible environment but some new updates have made it relatively resource intensive (Was receiving a `[CRITICAL] Worker Timeout message`.) In attempting to fix this issue I wanted to increase the number of CPUs for my app.

**app.yaml**:

```
env: flex 

entrypoint: gunicorn -t 600 --timeout 600 -b  :$PORT main:server

runtime: python
threadsafe: false

runtime_config:
  python_version: 2


automatic_scaling:
 min_num_instances: 3
 max_num_instances: 40
 cool_down_period_sec: 260
 cpu_utilization:
 target_utilization: .5
resources:
 cpu: 3
```

After some time I receive:

> "Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred during deployment."

Is there some sort of permission issue preventing me from increasing the CPUs? Or is my app.ymal invalid?

Comment: Does YAML require at least _some_ spaces for section indents? I mean, you don't need a specific number of spaces to be an indent, and they don't have to be the same. But do you need at least one space indents?

Comment: I do not believe so as I can run the same app with cpu: .5 and it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: @jdv You can set the number of indentation independently in different blocks. Have look at the [documentation](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2777534)

Comment: @Yucci, you'll find that this link doesn't obviously address my question, and even says "Each node must be indented further than its parent node." The query was not about the the amount or if indentation is dependent, but rather "do child nodes have to be indented by at least one?" I don't know if "foo: bar: xxx" falls under the parent-child rule above, but at the end of the day I noticed that the example YAML seen here is different from every other example pertaining to Flask. This, in itself, is a good reason for a comment.

Comment: @jdv in above example only target_utilization: .5 needs to be indented apart from that it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can not set the [number of cores(CPU)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#cpu) to odd numbers except 1. It should be even.